# What is the difference between empty and single view applications for programmatically creating views?

Tags: ios, xcode

(I don't know if this is something specific or different with Xcode 4.2.)

I create my views / controllers programmatically and don't use interface builder or nibs etc. Can someone tell me what the difference is between creating a project that is an "empty" application versus a "single view" application? The former has just the app delegate, and the latter has a delegate and controller provided, but I was wondering if there was any difference I should be concerned with.

I typically aim to have my main/root controller create a root empty view on which I attach and detach views as I add/remove screens. My hunch is that I may as well go with the single view project but am wondering if there is any clutter that this project has that I should avoid by just making an empty project.

By the way, I use this empty root view because (if I recall correctly), there were some strange auto-rotation issues related with swapping out the root view (versus having a steady root view that simply swaps out its subview).  If this is a waste of time, I'd appreciate that being clarified as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in stating that the single view application template provides a pre built View controller (XIB, .h and .m files) for you to work on. And that is the only additional component that is added to the project.

Comment: So, to clarify, there is no difference at all between the single view project and manually adding a viewcontroller .m and .h to the empty proj? Thanks.

Comment: Yes.That's all there is to it.